# Как правильно организовать класс

Tags: c#

Добрый день!

Хочется унифицировать написание нескольких классов.
Если объяснять на кошечках:
Принципиально иметь коллекцию объектов. Есть один класс - куб. У него есть метод вычисления объема и несколько свойств. Есть другой класс - цилиндр, у него те же свойства и тот же метод вычисления объема, понятно что реализация отличается. И т.д.
Как создать объект класса List чтобы  в него могли быть затолканы объекты разных классов? Какой класс указывать при созднии List?

Comment: Объявить какой-то абстрактный класс или интерфейс и от него наследуйтесь и создайте коллекцию экземпляров абстрактного класса или интерефейса, а в чём вопрос? Ещё также в крайнем случае можно создать `List<object>`, затем проверять тип с помощью `as` и `is` или фильтровать методом расширения LINQ `OfType`.

Comment: Более интересен первый вариант. Объявляю класс figure. Со свойствами и пустым методом. Потом создаю класс Cilinder наследованный от figure и переопределяю метод. Тоже самое с Cube? Как создать List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока я готовил пример, Вам уже ответили, но на всякий случай добавлю пример

```
    interface IGeometry
{
    double VolumeCount();
}
class Sfera : IGeometry
{
    double diametr;
    public Sfera(double _diametr)
    {
        diametr = _diametr;
    }

    public double VolumeCount()
    {
        return 3.14 * 3 / 4 * diametr * diametr * diametr;
    }
}

class Cube : IGeometry
{
    double vertexSize;
    public Cube(double _size)
    {
        vertexSize = _size;
    }

    public double VolumeCount()
    {
        return vertexSize * vertexSize * vertexSize;
    }
}
```

Соответственно использовать как-то так:

```
            List<IGeometry> lstGeometry = new List<IGeometry>();
        lstGeometry.Add(new Cube(20.0));
        lstGeometry.Add(new Sfera(10.0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно это решить через интерфейс, всяко это будет лучше чем вариант с `List<object>`

```
public interface IHasVolume
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    double Volume { get; }
}

public class Cube : IHasVolume
{
    public double Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return 9;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cylinder : IHasVolume
{

    public double Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return 7.4;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //вот используем интерфейс
        List<IHasVolume> list = new List<IHasVolume>()
        {
            new Cube() { Name = "Куб" },
            new Cylinder() { Name = "Цилиндр" }
        };

        list.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine($"Фигура: {f.Name}={f.Volume}"));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Пойду читать про interface

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли получить элемент коллекции как отдельный объект, что-то с ним сделать и обратно вставить в коллекцию? Типа: TempObj = list [0]; TempObj.SetName ("temp"); list [0]=TempObj;  Как объявить в таком случае TempObj?

Comment: Как можно добавлять объект в коллекцию, в зависимость от внешних условий: if (1) Cylinder temp=new Cylinder; else Cube temp=new Cube; list.Add (temp)

Comment: @АлексейМайборода "...можно ли получить элемент коллекции как отдельный объект, что-то с ним сделать и обратно вставить в коллекцию?" для изменения объекта в коллекции его не нужно извлекать из коллекции, достаточно по индексу указать на него и изменить у него свойства. Второй вопрос не понял, так как вы и так все написали, что нужно делать.

Comment: Во втором случае, если я так пишу, то ругается на то что происходит вложенное объявление переменной

Comment: Пишет : Внедренный оператор не может быть объявлением или оператором с идентиыикатором

Comment: @АлексейМайборода мне нужно видеть код, так тяжело понять что и как. Задайте вопрос, покажите свой код. Такое в комментариях обсуждать неудобно.